# rsync: link_stat "/root/.ssh" failed: No such file or directory (2)

Tags: server, ssh, rsync

```
root@ubuntu:~# usermod -aG sudo user 
root@ubuntu:~# sudo visudo 
root@ubuntu:~#  mkdir /home/user
root@ubuntu:~# chown user:user /home/user -R
root@ubuntu:~# rsync --archive --chown=user:user ~/.ssh /home/nshd
rsync: link_stat "/root/.ssh" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1196) [sender=3.1.2]
```

loading a new remote server on Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Don't run `ssh` as root. Most systems won't let you log in as root anyway.

Comment: haha.. thanks. so now as the user acct i tried to look at the .ssh folder.. ```cd .ssh -bash: cd: .ssh: No such file or directory``` i'm not sure what i did wrong. the other server i set up did not have this problem they were both setup identically.